# Ensure that API calls are efficient

Tags: api, architecture

I'm integrating with the `Sport Radar` API. This is a pretty great API but I'm noticing it doesn't have a particular Endpoint that I was hoping to leverage.

I noticed that the API does not have a `Players` index call. In order to `get` all the players in the league you have to go through this process (Confirmed by the API team)

```
1) Call an endpoint that lists the ids of each team in the league.

2) For each Team id call an endpoint that gets each team and lists each player for each team.
```

All in all that is over `30` API requests for each time I need to run a fairly common function.

#### MY CURRENT SOLUTION:

Store the Players in the database. So instead of reaching out through the API every time I need to list the players. I can just make a DB query for the players. This solution seems heavy handed though, I'd like for my application to not have to keep track of the players.

#### MY QUESTION

What are some ways of solving this problem? Again the questions is: What are ways of avoiding many api calls in order to get common data? Is the best solution just to make the `30` api call each time? Thank you!

Comment: Now while an interesting question, it is a bit broad and opinion based. That said, is the requested data updated frequently from the external API?

Comment: @Nkosi No, the data should largely stay the same. It should probably be updated every few months or so.

Comment: Then keep your local database like a cache of sorts and not have to keep calling the external API. If the external API has some way of providing a way to tell that data was updated (like a last updated timestamp) then on you can have a secondary service whose sole purpose is to monitor when the data changes and update the cache (database)

Answer (score 0):

I am working with the sport radar API and we had a similar problem, to solve it we use a cache to have this information faster and filtered, basically we connect a redis and run a cron in a service that updates the data (in our case each 24 hours).